# Jasper reports: Overlapped fields not shown in excel output

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Take the following example:

I have one very wide column (lets say 150pt), positioned on x=0
I have 2 columns of 25pt, positioned on x=100 and x=125. Thus, these are overlapping the first.

Depending on certain conditions (parameters to the report), I do or do not print the 2 overlapping columns. I do this by using the "print when expression ...".

This works like a charm when I use the PDF as output, but when I generate the report in excel, I do not get the big field, it is just missing. As long as I do not print the 2 overlapping fields, everything remains OK.

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the answer is no ... hopefully there is a better answer

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/503288/missing-columns-excel

> ... the columns are overlapping.  And the so-called "grid
>   exporters" like the HTML, XLS  and CSV exporters do not support
>   overlappging elements.  The elements that are behind do not print.
>
> I hope this helps.  Teodor